# Help with stylized hair

Tags: modeling, hair, 3d-printing, boolean-modifier

I can't seem to find a way to cut out the spikes of hairs going inside the head. I would like to 3D print the hair separately and glue it to the head.

I tired bool tool slice and some other methods but nothing works.

[image: head with hair]

[image: hair spikes]

Comment: maybe try the remesh tools?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: It seems to me Remesh was used already ... Probably try to use some Sculpt brush with Dyntopo enabled (mask out the area first).